# Code in signal not being executed

Tags: python, django

I want to prevent the products from being deleted when deleting a brand. Here's my code:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from shop.models import Brand, Product


def before_deleting_brand(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Detach products from the brand upon brand deletion
    """

    Product.objects.filter(brand=instance).update(brand=None) <<< LINE HAS NO EFFECT


pre_delete.connect(before_deleting_brand, sender=Brand)
```

Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether there is any model that indirectly links `Product` model to `Brand`.

BTW, specifying [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) argument is easier way to prevent deletion of the referencing object.

For example:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for on_delete=models.SET_NULL.

Comment: @AdamSilver, What was the problem? Is there another indirect link between `Product` and `Brand`?

Comment: I don't think there's an indirect link, not sure why it's not working. on_delete worked perfectly and it's much cleaner anyway.